# nesting/crossing in lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, nested-data

My question relates to the excellent answer given to this question a couple of years ago "Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?"
The answer used the examples of classes within schools, where each of 3 schools had 3 classes that made up a nested structure of classes within schools. Here classes 1 to 3 in each school had no particular relationship and no expectation that class 1 in a school would be more like class 1 in the other schools (a random factor). 
My question is how would you treat a situation where classes 1, 2 and 3 did have some relationship across schools - for example: class 1 = a novice teacher; class 2 = a moderately experienced teacher; class 3 = a very experienced teacher? Here you might expect teacher experience to be important, but that effect occurs within the context of each specific school.

Comment: If you know that to be true then you can add teachers as a fixed effect.

Answer (score 3):

As eluded to in the comments, the situation where there is a systematic effect of the teacher, in this case the experience of the teacher, then one approach would be to include the number of years experience of the teacher as a fixed effect. It would be advisable to still include the class as a random effect, as there will likely be other, unmeasured, reasons for variation at the class level.